# Facebook FQL Query not returning results in certain cases

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I'm trying to get the number of total fans for certain pages.

To do this I'm using the following HTTP get for example on page id:462790137094807 https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D462790137094807

But, for certain pages id, for example: 378009835566560
I'm getting an empty result though the page has some fans.
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D378009835566560
or another example:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D149294551780718

Why the hell Facebook doesn't return correct values ? Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page `378009835566560` has a user restriction imposed on it. It either blocks users from some countries or of some ages. I can see in the USA, so I'm guessing it's an age restriction.

You can't get that page's data unless you have authenticated with a user access token who meet's the page owner's criteria.

To test this, attempt to visit http://facebook.com/378009835566560 from a browser where you aren't logged into Facebook. You'll get a "not found" error. Visit from a logged in browser and you'll see the page (if you meet the criteria).